# Unity URP weird looking lightmap issue

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development, urp

if i apply lightmap i get this result :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaJRu.png

Lightmap Preview :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUmZ1.png

Lightning Settings :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGjOd.png

I don't know if it's related to the material, but I'm putting the screenshot here anyway :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1cgz.png

I'm also using Unity version 2020.3.12f1 and URP v10.5.

Answer (score 0):

Could you increase the lightmap resolution from the lighting settings and also the Max lightmap size.

Also , the GPU lightmaper looks like it is in preview which can cause some bugs , can you try CPU and see if it changes anything.